# Screen problem (Debian9 - xfce - ThinkPad x250)

Tags: debian, xfce

This is a strange thing i am seeing every now and then since 10 days. My screen starts to flip very randomly and fastly, like changing between workspaces very fast. I still have no idea why and when it happens (it happens for me randomly if i touch the mouse pad or press some keys). I was running Debian 9 since yesterday, so it started to happen more and more, so i did a backup and reinstalled the Debian with the xfce desktop. Strangely it still happens! So should i think that it has something to do with my Hardware, since it still hasn't stopped after a fresh install?

Here are some pictures of this as it happened and a link to a video (Workspaces pass from right to left at an extremely high speed, and i am not able to do anything unless doing a hard reboot):

[The Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGCq34r5tRI&feature=youtu.be)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any one has a same problem can help?

**Edit**

I could think (but i am still not sure) that this happens every time i am working in the terminal.

Comment: I'd guess that whichever key press is normally used to achieve the effect you're describing is being triggered by a physical issue (problem with the keyboard?) - next time it happens, take the keyboard connection out (I assume it's physical rather than wireless) and see if it stops happening.  Try with a different keyboard.  If it's wireless, replace the batteries.

Comment: @EightBitTony I am using a ThinkPad X250 Laptop, no external keyboard

Comment: You are not alone! I have the exact same problem running Debian 9 and Gnome Desktop on a x250. Started happens like a week ago (or something). I did install the latest Firefox version from Sid but uninstalled it later on. But I don't think that this is related since you have the same problem. This problem occurs both when the laptop is docked and using an external display and when it is not.

Comment: @NiclasNilsson i think it has something to do with debian 9 and the graphic card of my thinkpad x250. I tried many desktops (Cinnamon, XFCE, LXDE, Mate) and the problem was still there. I changed to Ubuntu Studio about a week ago and since then haven't seen that happen again.

Comment: @amirteymuri Yeah, I also have the feeling that it is related to graphic card. I might just go to Ubuntu also if I can't find another way to fix it. Good to know that Ubuntu works for you! Thnx for answering my comment!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else have the same problem. @amirteymuri seems to solved it by installing a different distro. My problem was not only that the screen behaved strange, the system also started to freeze. But downgrading the kernel from 4.9.0-4 to 4.9.0-3 seems to have solved both the graphic problem and the freezing.

My solution below assumes you running a 64 bit system.

**DISCLAIMER:** I only show what have worked for me, I won't take any responsibility if this breaks your system.

First, make sure you have 4.9.0-3 installed (if you not already know that you have). Run this as the `root` user:

```
apt install linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Now you can try running this kernel by restarting the system and choose to run GNU/Debian with advanced flags and then choose this kernel version.

If it seems to work you can remove the newer (non working) kernel. Run this as the `root` user:

```
apt purge linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-4-common linux-headers-4.9.0-4-amd64
```

Good luck! :-)